# Why is the database id of the last inserted object always 0?

Tags: android, database, android-room

In the below method, I'm inserting an object into a table and then calling a method to return the id of that object just added; I need its id to place into *another* cross reference table. Every time I insert the two ids into this cross reference table, however, the gamebook id is always 0, even though when I inspect the gamebooks table in the database inspector, it's clearly being assigned an id by Room (using auto increment). What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveGamebookClicked(Gamebook gamebook, int collectionId) {

    mainViewModel.insertGamebook(gamebook);
    long id = mainViewModel.getLastId();

    CollectionWithGamebooksEntity collectionWithGamebooksEntity = new CollectionWithGamebooksEntity(collectionId, id);
    mainViewModel.insertCollectionWithGamebooks(collectionWithGamebooksEntity);
 }
```

Here's the Dao method:

```
     @Insert
     long insert (Gamebook gamebook);
```

Here's the Dao method I'm using to get the id of the last gamebook added:

```
     @Query("SELECT gamebookId FROM gamebooks_table")
     long getLastID();
```

Comment: Are you retrieving the id (generated primary key) i.e. is the function, in the class annotated with `@Dao`, annotated with `@Insert`? Does the function return the long and is that long then used to set the value of LastId in the mainViewModel. If not then being a primitive the default value will be 0 and hence a likely cause of your issue.

Comment: Hi Mike, I just updated the original post with the Dao method. That function is returning a long, but I'm not using it in the ViewModel to set the value of lastId. (I've been trying to set the lastId value in MainActivity.) Is this something that should be done in the ViewModel, as opposed to the MainActivity where I'm currently doing it? I don't need the gamebook id for displaying to the UI or anything; I just need it to copy into the cross reference table along with the collection id (i.e., a gamebook is considered to be "in" a collection, so I need to link the two entities).

Comment: You need to retrieve/catch/store the gamebook id when you do the insert so that it is available for applying it to the cross reference (or use an alternative function to ascertain the id from the database if you can otherwise specifically identify the appropriate row).

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm using the Dao method which I've added to my question to get the last id. Now it's just returning the first id (i.e., 1) for each new gamebook that's been added. This is driving me nuts. I thought getting the id of the last inserted object into a table would be a cinch, but it's just eluding me.

Comment: That query would return a list BUT then as you only have long as the returned value. It will return the first. `SELECT max(gamebookId) FROM gamebooks_table` will  typically work. Still it's much better to utilise the value returned from the insert as if a row isn't inserted then -1 will be returned. Which if not considered could mess up the relationships.

Comment: I've noticed that if i redeploy the app to the emulator and call getId() again, it returns the id of the object that was last added before I redeployed. And then it just keeps returning that same id for all subsequent additions to the table. If I redeploy the app again, it will return the id I added the first time I redeployed the app. And so on. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's experiencing the same problem, I found that my issue was being caused by having the observer in the wrong place. When I moved the observer to my Activity's onCreate() method, and checked to make sure there was something to actually observe (e.g., when the app is run for the first time, there's nothing to observe because nothing has been added to the database), everything worked.